# Using bash scripting How do I check if a string is inside another string

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm using bash scripting to execute `psql`(database) commands:

The command returns an answer that contains or not the database/table name.

How do I check if my database/table is in the returned answer?
Pseudo:

```
VAR_EXIST=$(command)
if $DATABASE_NAME in VAR_EXIST then
 VAR_EXIST= true
```

Comment: Answered on StackOverflow in https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1540660

Comment: @ArtGertner add it as answer here - giving credit, of course :)

Comment: 2562 upvotes???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1540660

```
string='a needle in a haystack'
if [[ $string = *"a needle"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Note that spaces in the needle string need to be placed between double quotes, and the * wildcards should be outside.

Adapted to your case:

```
VAR_EXIST=$(command)
if [[ $VAR_EXIST = *"$DATABASE_NAME"* ]]; then
  echo "DB exists!"
fi
```